# How to Setup a Discord BOT with Phyton

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I did this following a tutorial, but when I play run it says there is an error on line 5

```
import discord
import os
my_secret = os.environ['token']

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content.startswith('Hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello')

client.run(os.getenv('token'))
```

Comment: Please share what the error says.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of advice: post the errors you're getting so people don't have to run the code to get an idea of what's happening. Anyway I ran it and saw

```
➜  test-discordbot poetry run python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/l4sh/Projects/test-discordbot/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    client = discord.Client()
TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

According to the documentation you need to pass the intents to initialize the client.

```
discord.Client(*, intents, **options)
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#client

You can find more about the intents you can use with discord.py in

- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#intents
- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

So your client initialization becomes something along the lines of

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
```

or something else depending on your intents configuration in the discord side